# Inputed text in a range causes another range to be deleted

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 macros that run within one sheet. The one macro only affects copying and pasting where as the other will depending on the userform filldown, border and input text from comboboxes/textbox.

For some reason within the worksheet (Monthly FGL Report) when I input anything into the next available cell in Column A, the previous Row of column AM (which as a iferror vlookup formula) will cause an error. This goes on for any cell below in Column A.

I have no idea why this is happening. Below is the main code. If you have any ideas as to why this would happen that would help also.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ColA As New Scripting.Dictionary  'Need Microsoft Scripting Runtime Reference
Dim ColB As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Criteria1 As Boolean
Dim Criteria2 As Boolean
Dim C As Range

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

With wb.Sheets("Master Fronting Room List")
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'This gets the last row on column A
For Each C In .Range("A1:A" & LastRow) 'loop through the whole column
On Error Resume Next
    'If you have duplicated entries this will throw an error
    ColA.Add C.Value, C.Row 'add the values from column A to DictA, also store it's row for later purposes
    ColB.Add C.Offset(0, 1).Value, C.Row 'add the values from column B to DictB, also store it's row for later purposes
Next C
'Criterias will give value of True if matched or False if not
Criteria1 = ColA.Exists(ComboBox2.Value) 'this is getting matched with ColA Dictionary
Criteria2 = ColB.Exists(ComboBox1.Value) 'this is getting matched with ColB Dictionary
If Criteria1 And Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 1
    Call linepick

ElseIf Criteria1 And Not Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 2
    .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
    .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
    Call linepick
    .Cells(LastRow, "B").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).AutoFill .Cells(LastRow, "B").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(2, 3)
    .Cells(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 0).Resize(2, 5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

ElseIf Not Criteria1 And Not Criteria2 Then 'SCENARIO 3
    .Cells(LastRow + 1, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
    .Cells(LastRow + 1, 2) = ComboBox1.Value
    .Cells(LastRow, "B").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 3).AutoFill .Cells(LastRow, "B").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(2, 3)
    .Cells(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 0).Resize(2, 5).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    With wb.Sheets("Connection Totals")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(LastRow, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        .Cells(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 21).AutoFill .Cells(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(2, 21)
        .Cells(LastRow, "A").Resize(1, 22).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With

    With wb.Sheets("Monthly FGL Report")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(LastRow, 1) = ComboBox2.Value
        .Cells(LastRow, "AE") = TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(LastRow, "AE").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(, 5).AutoFill .Cells(LastRow, "AE").Offset(-1, 1).Resize(2, 4)
        .Cells(LastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 0).Resize(2, 44).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
End If
End With

wb.RefreshAll
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Try commenting out the on error line to see what's going on. I can't see any code to insert a look up?

Comment: Would it be easier to take a look at my workbook?

Comment: Yes, if you could [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56529988/edit) to provide sample data and the problem `VLOOKUP` formula, it would be useful

Comment: A screenshot might help. Also read [mcve].